# Laravel relationships: How do I retrieve all courses to which a collection of assessment tests belong?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Am not a pro in neither PHP nor Laravel and I think I am cornered. In my assessment app, I have courses, lessons and assessment tests. An assessment_test has many to one relationship with lesson. lesson also has many to one relationship with course.
Now here is the problem, How do I retrieve all courses to which a collection of assessment_tests belong?
As shown in the code snippets provides, I tried to get around this by manually looping through the collection and saving the courses to an array but I got some weird error.

> Trying to get property 'course' of non-object

**Here is my problematic function**

```
public function index()
    {
        $attempts=AssessmentAttempt::all();
        $i=0;
        $courses=array();
        foreach ($attempts as $attempt) {
            // dd($attempt->lesson->course); 
            $courses[$i++]=$attempt->lesson->course;
        }
        dd(array_unique($courses));
        return view('achievements.index', ['attempts'=>$attempts, 'courses'=>$courses]);
    }
```

**AssessmentAttempt model**

```
public function lesson()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lesson::class);
    }
```

**Lesson model**

```
public function course()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
   }

public function assessmentAttempts()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(AssessmentAttempt::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the assesment_modal define the relation ship with course and make the course id column as a foreign_key in the assesment_model table

return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'foreign_key');

also design the relation in course model

return $this->belongsTo(Assesment_Model::class);

Comment: thanks but I was trying to avoid this. The assessment is related to a lesson which in turn is related to a course. I was hopping there's another way